# C++ templates: template argument error

Tags: c++, templates

I have

```
    template <typename ConcContainer>
    class WebBrowsingPolicyData
    {
    public:
        typedef ConcContainer<std::shared_ptr<WBRuleDetails>>::iterator iterator;
    ...
    private:
    ConcContainer<std::shared_ptr<WBRuleDetails>> usersData_;
    CRITICAL_SECTION critSection
```

I get a compile error at line (Error    6   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';')

```
typedef ConcContainer<std::shared_ptr<WBRuleDetails>>::iterator iterator
```

How can I make a typedef inside the template ? I must be missing something..

Comment: This looks confusing: Is `ConcContainer` a typename or a template?

Comment: ConcContainer is actually a template that's why hmjd answer is valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConContainer is itself a template so it needs to be a template template parameter:

```
template <template <typename T> class ConcContainer>
class WebBrowsingPolicyData
{
public:
    typedef typename ConcContainer<std::shared_ptr<WBRuleDetails>>::iterator iterator;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. The compiler is having trouble with `>>`.  Insert a space.  Note that if you're using a C++11-conformant compiler, this should not be an issue.

example:

```
typedef ConcContainer<std::shared_ptr<WBRuleDetails> >::iterator iterator;
```

1. `ConcContainer` doesn't have a member or typedef `iterator`.  Check to make sure that it really does.

EDIT:  This is not the most vexing parse.

Comment: I have conformant compiler VC 2010. I am not instantiating there the WebBrowsingPolicy...So must be something else.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not the most vexing parse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: @obmarg:  Well, whadya know!  You're right -- I've always thought of this incorrectly.  Edited.